# Run parallel promises and discard rest when two of them resolved

Tags: node.js, promise

I want to collect data from 10 different servers at the same time and when i got response 2 of them, i want to ignore/skip others. I solved this with promise.all() When i got 2 response, i call reject instead of resolve and do my job in catch(). But this seems a bit tricky to me, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want fast fail if any of the promises reject?  Or do you want to ignore errors as long as there are enough left that could reach your required number of completions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something similar to the BlueBird [Promise.some](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html) method suggested by @Neverever

```js
function awaitSome(promises, count) {
    if (!Array.isArray(promises) || promises.length < count) {
        return Promise.reject();
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const results = [];
        const errors = [];
        let completed = false;

        promises.forEach((p) => {
            p.then((result) => {
                if (!completed) {
                    results.push(result);
                    if (results.length === count) {
                        completed = true;
                        resolve(results);
                    }
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                if (!completed) {
                    errors.push(err);
                    if (promises.length - errors.length < count) {
                        completed = true;
                        reject(errors);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And the usage whould be

```js
awaitSome(
    [
        Promise.resolve(1),
        Promise.reject(1),
        Promise.resolve(1),
        Promise.resolve(1)
    ],
    2
)
    .then((results) => {
        console.log(results);
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
        console.error(errors);
    });
```

Comment: This assumes the OP does not want fast fail (e.g. fail as soon as any of the requests reject).  It wasn't clear from the question if they want fast fail or ignore errors as long as the required number could still finish.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct two `Promises` and put their `resolve`s into an array. When one response comes back, `pop()` one of the `resolve`s and call it. Repeat for the second response. Further responses can be ignored because the array is now empty.

Then, you can call `Promise.all` on the two constructed Promises, which will resolve when both `resolve`s have been called.

```js
const api = () => new Promise(res => {
  const timeout = Math.random() * 3000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('resolving ' + timeout);
    res(timeout);
  }, timeout)
});

const resolves = [];
const prom1 = new Promise(resolve => resolves.push(resolve));
const prom2 = new Promise(resolve => resolves.push(resolve));

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  api().then(res => {
    if (!resolves.length) return;
    resolves.pop()(res);
  });
}
Promise.all([prom1, prom2])
  .then(([res1, res2]) => {
    console.log('got 2 responses', res1, res2);
  });
```

As you can see in the code above, although the latest 3rd to 10th API calls resolve, the `Promise.all` resolves as soon as the first and second quickest resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the BlueBird `Promise.some`

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html

> Given an Iterable(arrays are Iterable), or a promise of an Iterable, which produces promises (or a mix of promises and values), iterate over all the values in the Iterable into an array and return a promise that is fulfilled as soon as count promises are fulfilled in the array. The fulfillment value is an array with count values in the order they were fulfilled.
>
> This example pings 4 nameservers, and logs the fastest 2 on console:

```
Promise.some([
    ping("ns1.example.com"),
    ping("ns2.example.com"),
    ping("ns3.example.com"),
    ping("ns4.example.com")
], 2).spread(function(first, second) {
    console.log(first, second);
});
```